# Arbitrary Unions of Closed Sets in Zariski Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I'm aware that, for an arbitrary topology $\tau\subset \mathscr{P}[U]$ on a set $U$, the collection $\tau^c$ of closed sets is only guaranteed to be closed under finite union.

In the Zariski topology, does this hold? Or does the Nullstellensatz guarantee that $\tau^c$ is closed under arbitrary union (following the observation that the ideal space is closed under arbitrary intersections)?

The context is a problem which parallels this one:

Let $G[1,n]\times \mathbb{P}^n$ be the product of the Grassmannian $G[1,n]$ and projective $n$-space $\mathbb{P}^n$. To every $g\in G[1,n]$ through the origin, associate the unique $\varphi_g\in \mathbb{P}^n$ satisfying $\varphi_g \in g$. Then, for every such $g$ there is a unique element $\alpha_g\;:=\;\big(g,\varphi_g\big)\in G[1,n]\times \mathbb{P}^n$.

Fix $g\in G[1,n]$, then the projection map

$$\big\{g\big\}\times \mathbb{P}^n\overset{p_2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{P}^n$$
is a homeomorphism onto its image. For every $g$, $\{\varphi_g\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$, so that $p_2^{-1}[\varphi_g]\;=\;\alpha_g$ is closed in the product topology.

Let $L\subset G[1,n]$, then, there is a closed $V\subset G[1,n]\times \mathbb{P}^n$ containing (the preimage of) $L$ which is given by

$$V\;=\;\bigcup_{\ell\in L}\alpha_\ell$$

If the Zariski topology is closed under arbitrary unions, then the argument runs without problem. Otherwise, this is only true when $L$ is countable.

So, is this true?

Comment: $\tau^c$ is definitely not closed under arbitrary union - for instance $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb A^1_\Bbb Q$ is dense (in particular not closed) but also a countable union of closed subsets.

Comment: @KReiser Okay cool, that's definitely true. What about if the base field is algebraically closed? For example, when $k=\mathbb{C}$, does the same argument hold? (dense sets are given by the arbitrary union closed sets?)

Comment: Same example works for the same reasons. For any field $k$, the closed subsets of $\Bbb A^1_k$ are the whole space and any finite set not containing the generic point, so any infinite subset is dense.

Comment: For general interest, I cannot resist the temptation here to mention that arbitrary union of closed subsets in a topological space are also known as Specialization closed subsets ... an old Theorem of Gabriel states that for every Commutative Noetherian ring $R$ , there is a one to one correspondence between the Specialization closed subsets (under Zariski topology) of Spec$R$ and Serre subcategories of the category of finitely generated $R$-modules ... this theorem and it's variations and generalizations have recently seen much activity ...

Comment: ... (continued from last comment) and for a very current short survey article on this , see  https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~takahashi/ipm-lectures-web-revised.pdf